# What kinds of verbal complement does the verb "request" accept and require?

Tags: word-usage, complements, mandative-subjunctive, infinitive-constructions

This verb has me a bit confused. I cannot submit my report personally and therefore have to resort to sending it by post. Now I need a polite way to ask to do this.

1. I request that I send my report via post.
2. I request that I be able to send my report via post.
3. I request the ability to send my report via post.
4. I request to send my report via post.

Which one of these is correct?

While I am here can you say *We all request to change the swimming timetable*, or do you have to have a you after the verb request like *We all request you to change the swimming timetable* even when he will not be doing the changing?

Answer (score 2):

2 and 4 are closest, but all must be changed a bit.

*6.  I **kindly** request **to be allowed to** send my report via post.*

*7.  I **kindly** request **being allowed to** send my report via post.*

*8.  I **kindly** request **the ability to** send my report via post.*

*9.  I **kindly** request **the ability of sending** my report via post.*

*10.  I **kindly** request **the capability of sending** my report via post.*

Alternatives using other verbs:

*11. I **would appreciate** **being allowed to** send my report via post.*

*12. I **would appreciate** **having the possibility of sending** my report via post.*

*13. I **would like** **to have the possibility to send** my report via post.*

See:

> ECEG2010-Proceedings of the 10th European Conference on ... David
> O'Donnell, ‎Academic Conferences - 2010
>
> eTaxes users fill their declaration on their computer and **have the
> possibility of sending** their data over the internet, as opposed to
> other Cantons such as Vaud, Valais or Geneva where users still have to
> print their tax declaration and send it ..
>
> __
>
> eTrust: Forming Relationships in the Online World - Page 52 Karen S.
> Cook, ‎Chris Snijders, ‎Vincent Buskens - 2009 -
>
> All Egos **have the possibility to send** all, some, or none of their
> points to their Alter.

Comment: Thank you Marius for the alternatives. Could you please tell me which of the ones I posted is the closest to making sense.

Comment: 8, 9, and 10 do not work. You don’t request an ability—you request permission, or a clause (infinitival or subjunctive). In this case, the most natural choice would be either permission (**“I kindly request permission to submit my report via post”**) or a subjunctive clause (**“I kindly request that I be allowed to submit my report via post”**).

Comment: #6 is probably the most idiomatic. I would also offer: "I kindly request that you accept my report via post."; "Would you please accept my report via post?"

Answer (score 0):

May I please send my report to you by post.

All of us request a change to the swimming timetable.

Answer (score 0):

*I request being able to send my report via post* is the best variant I guess.